# Merging two XMLs together in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I have these two XMLs that I want to merge together based on these conditions:

1. If any of the element is more than 7 weeks old, it has to be deleted.
2. If any of the element is newer with the same date (regardless of time), take everything from the new XML.

Sample XML:

```xml
<programme start="20150317173000 -0000" stop="20150317180000">
   <something else />
</programme>
```

I use `start` field to check if the element should be deleted or not.

```python
old_xml = ET.fromstring(old)
new_xml = ET.fromstring(new)

new_programmes = new_xml.findall('programme')

dates_to_delete = set()
programmes_to_add = []

for new_programme in new_programmes:
    start = new_programme.get('start')
    new_prog_st_t = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, DATETIME_FORMAT)
    new_prog_str_t = new_prog_st_t.strftime('%Y%m%d')

    dates_to_delete.add(new_prog_str_t)
    svn_wks = datetime.datetime.now(TIMEZONE) - datetime.timedelta(weeks=7)
    is_less_than_7_weeks = new_prog_st_t > svn_wks

    if is_less_than_7_weeks:
        programmes_to_add.append(new_programme)

all_programmes = old_xml.findall('programme')
for programme in all_programmes:
    start = programme.get('start')
    start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, DATETIME_FORMAT)
    svn_wks = datetime.datetime.now(TIMEZONE) - datetime.timedelta(weeks=7)
    is_older_than_7_weeks = start_time < svn_wks

    if is_older_than_7_weeks:
        old_xml.remove(programme)
    else:
        start_st_t = start_time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        if start_st_t in dates_to_delete:
            old_xml.remove(programme)

for p in programmes_to_add:
    old_xml.append(p)

return old_xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eliminate for loops where you can**

- You can probably be more aggressive with `list comprehensions`. I would replace your `for programme in all_programmes` with a list comprehension that calculated the date and created a list of indices to delete (but I suspect many others would vehemently disagree with this advice):

  `enumerated_programmes = enumerate(all_programmes)
  to_keep = [i for i,p in enumerated_programmes if datetime.datetime.strptime(p.get('start'), DATETIME_FORMAT) < svn_wks]
  ...
  all_programmes = [all_programmes[i] for i in to_keep]`

  You can make a second list of indices that should be replaced with a newer record, using similar logic.

**Naming**

- Why not use `old_programmes` as a name instead of `all_programmes` to make the binary nature of the code clear?

**Confusing code**

- Why is there a `return` statement at the bottom of your code? I didn't see any `def` statements so it's not clear what/why you're returning/

**Use available Python functions**

- There is no need to combine `append` with a `for` loop. Instead you can extend one list with another. Say you have `list a` and `list a`. Use `a.extend(b)` rather than appending each element of `b`. The code will be clearer, shorter, and more efficient.
- Similar to my advice above about using `list comprehensions` more aggressively, you could also using `filter` rather than `if, else` statements. This would take more logic out of your `for` loops, which is always a good thing.

**DRY**

- You compute `svn_weeks` in each iteration of each of your `for loops`but it's a constant for whatever day you are running it. You should compute it once, before either of your `for loops`.

Answer (score 1):

## Naming

Most of your naming is pretty good, there are a few variables that I'd consider renaming though.

- `svn_wks` - This is a pointless abbreviation. Since it is abbreviated, I don't know what `svn` means. This should be expanded to something like `???_weeks`.
- `new_prog_st_t`, `new_prog_str_t`, and `start_st_t` - These all have cryptic abbreviations, like `st`, or `t` which further obfuscate the meaning of the variable names. Preferably, you should only be using abbreviations if the abbreviation is clear enough, and maintains clarity and readability.
- `p` - In the `for` loop `for p in programmes_to_add:`, `p` should preferably be renamed to something like `program`, or `programme`.

---

## Nitpicks

You have two variables, `is_less_than_7_weeks`, and `is_older_than_7_weeks`. Rather than creating condition variables, I'd just write the two `if` statements like this:

```
if new_prog_st_t > svn_wks:
    programmes_to_add.append(new_programme)

...

if start_time < svn_wks:
    old_xml.remove(programme)
```

If you really think that the extra clarity is needed, you can always drop a few inline comments (`#`) above them.

---

Other than those issues, you code looks really good! Good job!